# Why should dom element be wrapped in an empty div while integrating jquery plugin in react Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am going through the react documentation article of [integrating-with-jquery-chosen-plugin](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#integrating-with-jquery-chosen-plugin), and react gives an example of the [Chosen jquery plugin](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and mentions the following:

> Notice how we **wrapped `<select>` in an extra `<div>`**. This is necessary because Chosen will append another DOM element right after the `<select>` node we passed to it. However, as far as React is concerned, `<div>` always only has a single child. This is how we ensure that React updates won’t conflict with the extra DOM node appended by Chosen. It is important that if you modify the DOM outside of React flow, you must ensure React doesn’t have a reason to touch those DOM nodes.

```
class Chosen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>        
        <select className="Chosen-select" ref={el => this.el = el}>          
          {this.props.children}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I initially thought that when react re renders `<App>` with new `setState()` call, if we don't have the extra `div` around the `select` then there would be trouble for the diffing algorithm and `dom` elements appended after `select` would be removed. But, apparently this is not whats happening. In terms of code:

```
<App>                   |                 |<App> 
  <Component1/>         |                 |  <Component1/>   
  <Chosen/>             | -- rerender --> |  <Chosen/>  //gets updated and removes nodes after <select>
  <Component2/>         |                 |  <Component2/> 
</App>                  |                 |</App>
```

I tried to imitate this situation and to my surprise, even if I don't wrap `select` in a `div`, it doesn't get updated and the extra dom nodes added after `select` stay intact:

```js
//class component Chosen
class Chosen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chosen: this.props.chosen,
    };
    //I haven't used this state, but even if the option tag has value as this state
    //On state update, the appended red input doesn't get deleted
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <select id="unique">
          <option value="one">one</option>
          <option value="two">two</option>
        </select>
    );
  }
}



class App extends React.Component {
  //create state for fancybtn1 and 2
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fancyBtn1: "one",
      fancyBtn2: "two",
    };

    //after 5 seconds update state
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        fancyBtn1: "three",
        fancyBtn2: "four",
      });
    }, 5000);

  }

  //componentDidMount
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    //grab #unique and append an input tag after it
    setTimeout(() => { //jquery plugin like dom manipulation //$("#unique").Chosen();
      const unique = document.getElementById("unique");
      const input = document.createElement("input");
      input.type = "text";
      input.style.border = "1px solid red";
      input.value = "test";
      unique.after(input);
    }, 2500);
  }




  render() {
    console.log("App render");
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App {this.state.fancyBtn1} </h1>
        <FancyBtn txt={this.state.fancyBtn1} />
        <Chosen chosen={this.state.fancyBtn1} />
        <FancyBtn txt={this.state.fancyBtn1} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

let FancyBtnCount = 0;

//create FancyBtn class based component which has state for txt
class FancyBtn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      txt: this.props.txt,
    };


    //set counter, which keeps track of how many times the component is instantiated
    //I couldn't do it properly atm.
    FancyBtnCount++;
  }

  //on component update
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { // I know gives deprecated warning 
    console.log("componentWillReceiveProps");
    //set state if prev state is different
    if (this.state.txt !== nextProps.txt) {
      this.setState({
        txt: nextProps.txt,
      });
    }
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>FancyBtn {FancyBtnCount} </h1>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.txt} />
        <button>{this.state.txt}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}







ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

After 2.5 seconds I add a red `input` dom node after `select` and after 5 seconds, I re render the whole app. Now why doesn't with the re render the react diffing algorithm remove the red `input`? What difference would it make if I wrap the `select` in an extra `div`? Basically I am looking for an explanation of the quoted react docs.

Comment: Because it says the documentation says it adds an element and React expects only one child for the component?

Comment: @epascarello Why does React expects only one child? How does React deal with the situation when it was thinking to see only one child, but finds multiple children?

Comment: https://dillionmegida.com/p/why-jsx-expressions-must-have-one-parent/

Comment: The `return` statement always returns one value, this is fundamental javascript. But you could avoid this problem by not using jQuery at all, because jQuery doesn't use React state and JSX. It's a bit of a bad combination even if it seems to work.

Comment: @Kokodoko _The return statement always returns one value, this is fundamental javascript._ if you see my second example in the question, I am returning two elements(red input added later) and react has no problem. I think when the docs say _However, as far as React is concerned, <div> always only has a single child._ they mean that even without wrapper `div` react is gonna ignore the appended element.

Comment: I just meant javascript in general always returns only one value. The only way to return more values is to wrap them in an array or object. In React, there may be all kinds of stuff going on "under the hood", but I think it's always safer to return one thing after a `return` statement, React or no React. Using a `<>` fragment may also solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

This is most likely not a complete answer, but too long to post it as a comment.

In this specific case you are defining a react component named Chosen:

```
class Chosen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>        
        <select className="Chosen-select" ref={el => this.el = el}>          
          {this.props.children}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In React, a component can **never** return multiple "top level" elements, because it wouldn't make any sense.

So an even simpler component like this:

```
class Chosen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>        
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

is "illegal", because a component has to always return only one "top level" element. If for some reason you want your component to return multiple elements like in the example above, you'd have to wrap them into a div:

```
class Chosen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                </div>
                <div>
                </div>
            <div>
        );
    }
}
```

and now you would be correctly returning only one top-level element, which then in turn has those two divs as a children.

So in your case if you were to do it like this:

```
class Chosen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (     
        <select className="Chosen-select" ref={el => this.el = el}>          
          {this.props.children}
        </select>
    );
  }
}
```

it wouldn't work (even though it looks like there is only one element) because the chosen library apparently works like so that it will turn that select component into something like this for example:

```
class Chosen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (  
        <div class = "chosen-select-label">My select</div>   
        <div class = "chosen-select">
          <select>
            <option></option>
            <option></option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class = "some-other-chosen-select-shenanigans">
          ...
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now React has a problem with this because the component is returning more than one element. However, if you wrap the select into a div, the result would be something like this:

```
class Chosen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div class = "chosen-select-label">My select</div>   
        <div class = "chosen-select">
          <select>
            <option></option>
            <option></option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class = "some-other-chosen-select-shenanigans">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and React will be happy again.

As far as I know though, this div-wrapping method is quite an old way to do things. More modern way is to use [React Fragments](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment).

As for why such rule exists, I've always thought about it similarly to JavaScript's ordinary functions, so something like this makes no sense:

```
function func() {
  return 1;
  return 2;
}
```

If we really want to return 1 and 2 though, we would wrap them into something such as an array:

```
function func() {
  return [1, 2];
}
```

Comment: You can use fragments to wrap multiple elements if you need to return multiple root elements from a component.

Comment: _Now React has a problem with this because the component is returning more than one element._ That's exactly what I did in my second example in the question, I added a _red input_ after the `select` element and then did a re render of the whole app. React didn't give any error, rather it worked smoothly.

Comment: @user31782 You are not really using react when you add that input component  like that. Even if your page uses React, the whole page doesn't necessarily have to be done with React. In your case you are "forcibly" appending that input into the dom (from React's standpoint) and not sort of registering it with React, so React ignores it from it's virtual dom and diffing. It's fine to have something done with React and something done without, but in your case you might run into weird problems and behavior since you are doing the mixing, in theory, within a React component which is not advisable.

Comment: @user31782 This might give you some insight to your situation: https://react.dev/learn/add-react-to-an-existing-project it doesn't exactly go through this exact situation, but the idea is the same - React doesn't, in a sense, "overtake" your whole web application.

Comment: I see what you mean. It is react best practice to have always only one element returned. But, I doubt that react doesn't register the appended red input, because then in the next render react shouldn't render that red input  at all, so it must somehow under-the-hood remember the actual dom. Also when react docs say _However, as far as React is concerned, <div> always only has a single child._ then wrapping `select` in a div should be unnecessary, because from react's perspective only `select` is being returned.

Answer (score -1):

React is unaware of changes made to the DOM outside of React. It determines updates based on its internal representation, and if the same DOM nodes are manipulated by another library, React gets confused and has no way to recover.
This does not mean it is impossible or even necessarily challenging to combine React with other ways of affecting the DOM, you have to be mindful of what each is doing.
The easiest way to avoid conflicts is to prevent the React component from updating. You can do this by rendering elements that React has no reason to edit, like an empty .

**How to Approach the Problem**

To demonstrate this, let’s sketch out a wrapper for a generic jQuery plugin.

We will attach a ref to the root DOM element. Inside componentDidMount, we will get a reference to it so we can pass it to the jQuery plugin.

To prevent React from touching the DOM after mounting, we will return an empty  from the render() method. The  element has no properties or children, so React has no reason to update it, leaving the jQuery plugin free to manage that part of the DOM:

```
class SomePlugin extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
  this.$el = $(this.el);
  this.$el.somePlugin();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.$el.somePlugin('destroy');
}

render() {
  return <div ref={el => this.el = el} />;
}
```

}

Solution Copied from React Official Documentation:
[React Documentation](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)

Comment: When the parent component(in our case root) updates, wouldn't it update the direct child(div in our case)? Now if root re-renders, it will re-render child div as well, in that case, wouldn't react remove all div's further children(added by somePlugin), when it does the reconciliation?